# Search value in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have following object im not sure how to proceed.

[Object image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kckHf.png)

How can I go through all objects and select the **content** **array** and **search for a value x**. And when the value x is in the object I need to **get the object title** from the object where the value was found.

Can anyone give me a hint how I can solve this problem?

Comment: are there nested objects or are there not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use for...in to iterate over the object and `indexOf()` to check if a key exists in the array content. something like this:

```
function searchVal(x){
     for(var key in obj){
         if(obj[key].hasOwnProperty('content') && obj[key].content.includes(x))
             return key;
     }
}
```

Comment: You could use .contains(x) instead of .indexOf(x)>=0

Comment: @Jonasw good call! haha, sorry I was just trying to be helpful and got mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for...in` to iterate the object keys, then a regular `for` loop to check the `content` array for your specific value:

```
function findTitle(x) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj[key].content.length; i++) {
            if (obj[key].content[i] === x) {
                return key;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let name = Object.values( obj /*your main object*/ )
       .find( obj => obj.content.includes(x) )
       .name;
```

You could *find* the first object in the *Objects values* of your main obj, that has a property *content* which *includes* x, then get the name of that object.